# BroadcastReceiver is not receiving local broadcast

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to extend the FCM service, and broadcast to the `MainActivity` upon `onNewToken()` being called. `onNewToken()` is indeed called, but the `onReceive()` method is not. As far as I know, I do not need to define anything else in the manifest, since this is a local broadcast. These are my classes:

*MainActivity.kt*

```
package com.reali.app.mymessagingapp

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener
import com.reali.app.mymessagingapp.MyFirebaseMessagingService.Companion.TOKEN_REFRESHED_EVENT
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId
import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var broadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver
    private lateinit var tvTitle: TextView
    private lateinit var tvToken: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        tvTitle = findViewById(R.id.tvTitle)
        tvToken = findViewById(R.id.tvToken)

        broadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                tvTitle.text = resources.getString(R.string.token_refreshed)
                refreshTokenText()
            }
        }

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(TOKEN_REFRESHED_EVENT))
        refreshTokenText()
    }

    private fun refreshTokenText() {
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult> { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                return@OnCompleteListener
            }

            val token = task.result?.token
            tvToken.text = token
        })
    }

}
```

*MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt*

```
package com.reali.app.mymessagingapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService

class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService()
{
    companion object {
        const val TOKEN_REFRESHED_EVENT = "token_refreshed_event"
    }

    override fun onNewToken(token: String?) {
        Log.d("MyFcmMessagingService", "Refreshed token: " + token!!)
        applicationContext.sendBroadcast(Intent(TOKEN_REFRESHED_EVENT))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Broadcasts sent via `Context.sendBroadcast()` are not local broadcasts, that's why you're not receiving them.

You need to use `LocalBroadcastManager` for the sending as well.

Instead of the following:

```
applicationContext.sendBroadcast(Intent(TOKEN_REFRESHED_EVENT))
```

**You should do something like this:**

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
        .sendBroadcast(Intent(TOKEN_REFRESHED_EVENT))
```

Also, do not forget to unregister your receiver when appropriate to avoid memory leaks:

```
// most likely in onDestroy() (since the registration is in onCreate())
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
        .unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver)
```